# Firebase Firestore not deleting a document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete document in firestore using deleteDoc(), but this not delete.
It's my code:

```
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);


let stRootDocument = `/${tipo}/${uid}`;
const refCol = doc(db,stRootDocument);

    
deleteDoc(refCol)
 .then(() => {
  console.log("Entire Document has been deleted successfully.")
})
 .catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

although, this dont delete.

My document don't have any subcollections, but don't delete, also I have tried:

to do the refer using:

```
const refCol = doc(db,"carousel","xgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

and after to pass this refer in the deleteDoc Method but too don't delete.
other form:

```
deleteDoc(doc(colRef,uid)).then((objR) => {
     return objR;
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

but, this too doesn't delete.

Comment: Do you get any error in the logs? Can you share a screenshot if yes?

Comment: Hi Dharmaraj in the vscode logs there isn´t about this.

Comment: there arent logs from vscode